# How to set row background color depending on age

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I have data grid control (jsGrid).
I would like to set row background color depending on age.

For example:
If a row has an age value below "30" then Its background color will be red.

here's the code in js:

```js
var clients = [
        { "Name": "Otto Clay", "Age": 25, "Country": 1, "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Connor Johnston", "Age": 45, "Country": 2, "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Lacey Hess", "Age": 29, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Timothy Henson", "Age": 56, "Country": 1, "Address": "911-5143 Luctus Ave", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Ramona Benton", "Age": 32, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #614-689 Vehicula Street", "Married": false }
    ];
 
    var countries = [
        { Name: "", Id: 0 },
        { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
        { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
        { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 }
    ];
 
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",
 
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
 
        data: clients,
 
        fields: [
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
            { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
            { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "Country", type: "select", items: countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
            { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsGrid"></div>
```

Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/rby9f57d/26/

The data in the grid is dynamic.
so I would like to set dynamically the background row color to red if the age is less than 30.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to refer to an external jsfiddle - the SO snippets are much easier to communicate and can be used by others to help you. I have edited your post accordingly.

Comment: In your sample data there isn't a single entry with an age less than 25 ;-) ...

Comment: A user could click the big green plus sign and add some data, and specify that the age be under 25 like 20...

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Thank you.
I edited that to an age less than 30 :)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while but I think I got something here: I introduced an event hanlder function "paint" that will step into action each time the table was refreshed or an item was edited. I attach it to the `onRefreshed` and `onItemEdited` events. Within the function I simply scan the table for occurences of the second column having a (numerical) value smaller than 30. And if that is the case I make the background of all `td` of that row red.

This is still very crude of course. Instead of directly setting a background-color it is often a better idea to add/remove a certain class that can control several css attributes.

```js
var clients = [
        { "Name": "Otto Clay", "Age": 25, "Country": 1, "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Connor Johnston", "Age": 45, "Country": 2, "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Lacey Hess", "Age": 29, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Timothy Henson", "Age": 56, "Country": 1, "Address": "911-5143 Luctus Ave", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Ramona Benton", "Age": 32, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #614-689 Vehicula Street", "Married": false }
    ];
 
    var countries = [
        { Name: "", Id: 0 },
        { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
        { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
        { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 }
    ];
 
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",
 
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        onItemUpdated: paint,
        onRefreshed: paint,
 
        data: clients,
 
        fields: [
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
            { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
            { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "Country", type: "select", items: countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
            { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });
    
function paint(ev){
  $("#jsGrid tbody tr").each((i,tr)=>{
    $(tr).children().css("background-color",+tr.children[1].textContent<30?"red":"");
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsGrid"></div>
```